# How to open files in a UIWebView?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller, webview, uistoryboard

I just make a file browser for iOS, I just need to know how to open any kind of file in a UIWebview. I think the webview can open any kind of file, that's because I chose to use a UIWebView to view the files directly in the app. Now my question.

How to programmatically switch to a UIViewController in the same UIStoryBoard and display the file? The file URL is stored in a string called `path`.

This is how fare I am, I just need to add the file viewer. [image]

Can someone help me?

Comment: why not use a fileManager? instead of UIWebView..

Comment: I don't know about this

Comment: read about NSFileManager...

Comment: OK, thanks. But how can I use NSFileManager to display the files? I use it to show the file path in a table view

Answer (score 0):

```
-(void) displayFile:(NSString*)fileName
{
  NSError *error = nil;
  NSString *documentsDirectory = [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory,   NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]; 
  TO get the filename
  NSString *folderPath = [documentsDirectory stringByAppendingPathComponent:fileName];  

  if (![[NSFileManager defaultManager] fileExistsAtPath:folderPath])  //Optionally check if   folder already hasn't existed.
  {
   // do something
  }
}
```

Hope this helps you...

Comment: Kind of, I need to know how to switch from the table view I show you in the post above to a UIWebView located in a UIViewController. I like to make a pushViewController animation.

Comment: use didSelectRowAtIndexPath method...  -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

Comment: I already have this, I just need to know the command to switch to the other UIViewController

Comment: inside the method, use [self pushViewController:otherViewController]

Comment: Sorry, but the Tableview and he other UIViewController are using the same ViewController files.

Comment: then have two separate views. Show the first view that shows all the files and folders. after selecting the row, show the second view with the correct image.